# How to play one animation with multiple views in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I want to play one animation with multiple views in android.
This is the simplified example of code.
This code works incorrectly.
Every startAnimation() call, affects all previously animated views

Please tell me, why it doesn't works and how to make it properly.

public SomeClass() {

```
private int currentViewID = 0; 
private View[] views = { view1, view2, view3, view4, view5 }
private Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out);

public SomeClass() {
    this.anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (SomeClass.this.currentViewID != SomeClass.this.views.length) SomeClass.this.hideNextView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

    });
    this.hideNextView();
}

private void hideNextView() {
    this.views[this.currentViewID++].startAnimation(this.anim);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on what your problem is ? As far as I undestand your code, you're trying to make each view fade out one after the other, is that it ?

Comment: Yes it is. but every time when I call viewN.startAnimation() method, fade animation plays to all previously faded views too

Comment: It might be the case that when you call startAnimation() you attach the animation object to the view. Consequently every time you start the animation all the views binded with this animation will be affected. Try having one animation for each view and see if the bug is still there.

Comment: Yes, in the case where each view has own animation it works. But in my app I have much more than 5 views like in example...

Comment: I'll post a full reply cause I need to put code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with many Animations in your class (one for each View) you could do things locally:

```
private int currentViewID = 0; 
private View[] views = { view1, view2, view3, view4, view5 }

public SomeClass() {
    this.hideNextView();
}

private void hideNextView() {
    final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out);

    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (SomeClass.this.currentViewID != SomeClass.this.views.length) SomeClass.this.hideNextView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

    });

    this.views[this.currentViewID++].startAnimation(anim);
}
```